# How to make z-index of the blocks below to be less than the one of the block above

Tags: html, css, z-index

**Task description**

There are number of block which contain absolutely positioned elements.
These absolutely positioned elements should overlap the absolutely positioned elements contained in the blocks below.

The solution to manually give z-indexes to the blocks is not good because the number of blocks is dynamic.

Are there any other solutions?

Attached code snippet for the task to be more clear. Please ask if you need more clarification on the task.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width; 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  height: 30px;
 }
 
 .inner.green {
   background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Some content 1
  <div class="inner">Should be above</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  Some content 2
  <div class="inner green">Should be below</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please specify other technologies to be used, this cannot be done dynamically with just HTML and CSS. Maybe you want to include JavaScript

Comment: @Daut Well, JS is an option. But I hoped only CSS(SASS) will do somehow ))

Comment: If you can tell me maximum number of blocks can be here then I have a solution for you, such as 3, 4 or 5 etc.

Comment: @Hanif Yeah, you can tell that, but it's not preferable because of the additional calculation... Anyway, I would like to see your solution, thanks.

Comment: So if you have 3 element then it can be: .wrapper:nth-child(1) {
        z-index:1; 
    }
    .wrapper:nth-child(2) {   
        z-index:2;  
    }
    .wrapper:nth-child(3) {
        z-index:3;  
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a counter that will be equal to the number of blocks that you will render, example:

```
5 boxes - var counter = boxes.length
```

And then while you iterate and render the boxes add:

```
style="z-index:[counter];" to the box 
and counter--
```

You should have something like:

```
box1 - z-index: 5
box2 - z-index: 4
etc...
```

Comment: I thought about that, but don't like the solution because of the every time calculation. Hoped for some css/sass solution... Thanks.

Comment: The calculation is pretty easy, you are looping through the elements every time anyway. I don't think it will hurt the performance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex to reverse the order of the elements so they stack naturally - but that would involve outputting the html in reverse order:

```css
.reverser {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.inner.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="reverser">
  <div class="wrapper">
    Some content 2
    <div class="inner green">Should be below</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    Some content 1
    <div class="inner">Should be above</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the problem, but I'd say it's not an elegant solution, and with this, logic adjustments (how the data is sorted) are required. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd say, if your server side code is producing this, then just use an increment in your loop and add the z-index inline would be the neatest way of doing things - there's no easy / elegant way using css alone other than manually adding a line for each child up to the max number you need